# fadeOut() function with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, transition

I'm trying to create a transition effect between images without success.

I'm using this code that works fine, unfortunately the images change without any effect.

```
    var images = [
  "https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx",
  "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cat-black-superstitious-fcs-cat-myths-162286659.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg"
]

var imageHead = document.getElementById("image-head");
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vvwcfkfr/1/

I've try thousand of solution this week with fadeIn, fadeOut, without any success.

I'm looking to create a transition effect like the slider on the Ryanair's homepage.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Where in your code is the part that related to the fadeIn/Out?

Comment: which part of your code do you think should make an "effect"

Comment: Right now the code doesn't have any part that reproduce the fade effect. I'm looking for any piece of code that reproduce the effect of the Ryanair website. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about jquery fade in fade out.   https://jsfiddle.net/vvwcfkfr/121/

```
setInterval(function() {
      $('#image-head').fadeOut("slow",
        function() {
          imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
          i = i + 1;
          if (i == images.length) {
            i = 0;
          }
          $('#image-head').fadeIn("slow")
         }
        );

      }, 2000);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I looking for. Many thanks Bryan.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the obtained offect is a little bit "ugly", how can I obtain a effect like the ryanair website?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `transition: background-image 0.3s;` in CSS to achieve fade between images, but they have to be the same size. Otherwise there will be also resizing animation.